# Codeigniter mail attachment encoding issues

Tags: email, codeigniter

I'm sending a email with attachment via a form and I'm having different results depending on the server. My dev server shows everything ok, but the production server shows **bad encoding** of the email message (accented characters) and the **attachment is replaced** by a ATT00001.txt‎ file (which is base64 encode).

I'm sending the email as plain text and I should emphasize that it's working perfectly in my dev server which uses smtp too but uses a gmail address. The production server seems to use a kind of MS Outlook Server or such, but is offsite and out of my reach.

This is how the email arrives using the production server:

```
>     Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>     
>     Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>     
>     Datos Personales:
>     
>     Puesto: Otro test
>     
>     Nombre y Apellido: name
>     
>     DirecciÃ³n: rhdireccion
>     
>     TelÃ©fono: rhtelefono
>     ...
```

These are my email setting in my config file:

```
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$config['mailtype']  = 'text';
$config['charset']   = 'iso-8859-1';

$config['rrhh'] = 'xxx@xxxxxxx.com';
```

I've tried changing the charset to utf-8 and it made no difference. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience , using [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) (after converting to a codeigniter library) has been more reliable and useful. Start with [this](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PHPMailer/)